# Add & delete view from Layout

Tags: android

How can I add & delete a view from a layout?

Comment: what kind of layout? could you please paste part of the code you are working on?

Comment: How is this well prepared?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

I've done it like so:

```
((ViewManager)entry.getParent()).removeView(entry);
```

Comment: In the newer SDKs its `(ViewGroup)` :)

Comment: @schwiz how can we reset the view id's in this case.My problem is even after my activity finishes whenever the next view gets added the view id gets incremented.I want the view id to default to 1 when i get back to this activity again.

Comment: ViewGroup extends View implements ViewParent, ViewManager. nicer to call it with casting to (ViewGroup)

Answer (score 27):

Use ViewStub and specify the layout of the view you want to toggle. 
To view:

```
mViewStub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or mViewStub.inflate();
```

To disappear:

```
mViewStub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Hiding is not the same as removing.

Comment: If you want to hide/unhide you could use .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) and .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). When the view is invisible the user can't interact with it.

Comment: Let's say I have a textView with an onClickListener attached to it. If I make it  disappear and then I tap on it, will the event still fire?

Answer (score 23):

This is the best way

```
LinearLayout lp = new LinearLayout(this);
lp.addView(new Button(this));
lp.addView(new ImageButton(this));
// Now remove them 
lp.removeViewAt(0); // and so on
```

If you have xml layout then no need to add dynamically.just call

```
lp.removeViewAt(0);
```

Comment: What will be the diff in terms of performance? I mean the performance diff of adding them dynamically or putting them into a static xml layout file and let it be inflated ?

Answer (score 21):

To add view to a layout, you can use `addView` method of the `ViewGroup` class. For example,

```
TextView view = new TextView(getActivity());
view.setText("Hello World");

ViewGroup Layout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
layout.addView(view);
```

There are also a number of remove methods. Check the documentation of [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).
One simple way to remove view from a layout can be like,

```
layout.removeAllViews(); // then you will end up having a clean fresh layout
```

Comment: removeAllViews() is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

Great anwser from Sameer and Abel Terefe. However, when you remove a view, in my option, you want to remove a view with certain id. Here is how do you do that.

1, give the view an id when you create it:

```
_textView.setId(index);
```

2, remove the view with the id:

```
removeView(findViewById(index));
```

Answer (score 6):

For changing visibility:

```
predictbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

For removing:

```
predictbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: It fixed my problem, more than every other answer. Useful if like me, your background or some params prevent the view to disappear totally.

Comment: it is because View.GONE don't remove the view for the layout, only make it invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use addView or removeView

**java:**

```
// Root Layout
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// TextView
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Sample");

// Add TextView in LinearLayout
linearLayout.addView(textView);

// Remove TextView from LinearLayout
linearLayout.removeView(textView);
```

**kotlin:**

```
// Root Layout
val linearLayout = LinearLayout(context)
linearLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

// TextView
val textView = TextView(context)
textView.text = "Sample"

// Add TextView in LinearLayout
linearLayout.addView(textView)

// Remove TextView from LinearLayout
linearLayout.removeView(textView)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin Reusable Extension Solution

#### Simplify removal

Add this extension:

```
myView.removeSelf()

fun View?.removeSelf() {
    this ?: return
    val parent = parent as? ViewGroup ?: return
    parent.removeView(this)
}
```

#### Simplify addition

Here are a few options:

```
// Built-in
myViewGroup.addView(myView)

// Null-safe extension
fun ViewGroup?.addView(view: View?) {
    this ?: return
    view ?: return
    addView(view)
}

// Reverse addition
myView.addTo(myViewGroup)

fun View?.addTo(parent: ViewGroup?) {
    this ?: return
    parent ?: return
    parent.addView(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi if are you new in android use this way
Apply your view to make it gone 
GONE is one way, else, get hold of the parent view, and remove the 
child from there..... 
else get the parent layout and use this method an remove all child
parentView.remove(child)

I would suggest using the GONE approach...

Comment: GONE will effectively hide the view but it won't remove it from the layout

Comment: Simple use the parentView.remove(removeViewName);

Comment: You're right about that, but I was trying to hint that you weren't answering the question by providing the "GONE" solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am removing view using start and count Method, i have added 3 view in linear Layout.

view.removeViews(0, 3);