# Iphone versus Android 's equivalent of Closing the view

Tags: android, iphone, view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [add and remove views in android dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically)

In Iphone, the view is added or remove by using addsubview or removefromsuperview. 
What about in Android, how do you add or remove a view?

fundamental questions, I am trying to clear up my concepts.

thanks

Comment: Take a look at [Add and Remove Views in Android Dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995215/add-and-remove-views-in-android-dynamically) and [Add Delete View From Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805599/add-delete-view-from-layout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to understand programmatically adding and removing views in iOS

In android, you cannot necessarily add a view to a view.  You will need a subview of the Class `ViewGroup` (`RelativeLayout`,`FrameLayout`...) that you can add views into.

You can use

```
void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(View child)
void android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(View view)
```

There are more ways to add and removeView, but the important part is that you look up the reference for [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).  Android layout is a whole different cup of tea compared to iOS layout.