# Program running  slow, because there are many objects.

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have a simple game, this game is about protecting baby from flies, so we must click the flies to kill it and save the baby. the flies is using imageview.

But I have a problem, I have a timer that every second create one flies, so if in level 1 is 50seconds , theres 50 imageview in my layout.

This make my program running so slow.

How  to solve this problem? should I delete the imageview when its out of the layout? but what is the code? I cant use remove view because its open windows classfile editor.

Any help/tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805599/add-delete-view-from-layout)

I believe this is a very easy solution

```
mViewStub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then when its removed from sight release the memory.

Comment: i have do that ..but its still running so slow .. :( any other solution guys??