# Removing buttons programmatically

Tags: java, android, button

In my code I create buttons programmatically as I do not know how many I need until a file is parsed

```
buttons= new LinkedList<Button>();
    for(int i=0; i< aList.size();i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(i);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn.setText(stringList.get(i));
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        buttons.add(btn);
        layout.addView(btn);
    }
```

This works fine, I'm just wondering if there is a quick way to delete all these buttons before creating more (I change the values of the buttons to new ones when the user presses an seperate button)

Comment: remove(button) is the simple answer. For more complicated answers, you may want to add more code and/or details to your question

Comment: Do these buttons need to be removed completely or just have the text changed and maybe what they do?

Comment: Instead of creating a bunch of buttons and removing them if they're not needed, why don't you parse your file and only create the buttons you need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved the problem with another for loop

```
for(int i=0; i< aList.size();i++)
    {
        Button btn;
        btn = buttons.get(i);
        layout.removeView(btn);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this

```
View v = (View) findViewById(id);
((ViewManager)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
```

Found here: [Add & delete view from Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805599/add-delete-view-from-layout)

Answer (score 3):

You can set invisible.

```
myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: The button becomes visible again if we rotate the screen.