# how to move a view from viewgroup into another viewgroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF4D00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF4D00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I wanna move the @button1 into @linear2, and the attributes belong button1 can't lost, include click lisener. then, the @linear1 is gonna be empty. like cut operation. How can I do?

Answer (score -1):

you need to add and remove the button pragmatically from ur activity class

this may help
[Add & delete view from Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805599/add-delete-view-from-layout)