# How to check for previous interstitial ad whether still shown or not?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have three activities, I want to show interstitial ad in the second and third `Activity`.

The user may open both `Activity` after each other, the result will be two interstitial ads shown.

How to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [this (updated link)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener) link which shows how you can use adbmob ads listener to get callbacks depending upon the present state of an ad.

Use AdListener to receive such callbacks, here's a sample of how you can do this.

```
   adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(){
        }
      });
```

so, if an ad is already onscreen don't show another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the link is not working , and the method onPresentScreen not found

Comment: Sorry mate, wasn't aware of changes in latest admob version, have changed the link and updated the answer, here you can use onAdOpened() and onAdClosed() for checking is ad is still visible or not.. and always load new ad inside onAdClosed()

Comment: Thanks again but sorry , i want to detect whether it is open or not (boolean) like (isLoaded) but i don`t see (isShown). Do you have any idea how to do so ?

Comment: You can manually remove your unwanted InterstitialAd instance from the view hierarchy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805599/add-delete-view-from-layout. For example, Activity 2 has Interstitial A, and Activity 3 has Interstitial B. If the user opens both activities (2 --> 3), you can remove your interstitial ad that is opened on Activity 2 (by removing it from Activity 2's layout).