# Why view is still showing after removing from layout

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view

Why my view is till showing shade after removing from layout. i have tried `view.postInvalidate();` and other method 
 what is solution for that
here is the image

[image]

Comment: Use view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: you didn't show how you remove it from layout. I think you do it incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how have you written your code.

You can try this:

```
  ((ViewManager)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
```

or this is how it is done normally:

**Android remove view from parent**

```
  View myView = findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
  ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView.getParent();
  parent.removeView(myView);
```

**Android remove all child views**

```
  LinearLayout formLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.formLayout);
  formLayout.removeAllViews();
```

You can refer the following answer:

[Add & delete view from Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805599/add-delete-view-from-layout)

Comment: i have removed the views, now after removing it is showing the shad, like in image i have posted here, layout is not refreshing

Comment: that is correct but what code have you used to remove it? Also, why not hide the view instead of removal as it might need the system to redraw the screen elements?

Answer (score 0):

In Layout, you can use: `android:visibility="gone"`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/layout_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

In Activity(java) :

```
LinearLayout llone= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llone);// change id here

layone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```